# Codeigniter populating dynamic link for each distinct value from a column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am successful by listing distinct values from a column on a table (this is the model)

```
$this->db->select('Uo2_Lot_No');
$this->db->distinct();
$query = $this->db->get('consignment');
return $result = $query->result_array();
```

I can view the distinct value on my view

```
<?php foreach($get_consignment as $row): ?><tr>
<td><a href="<?= base_url('admin/consignment1/con_table/' .$row['Uo2_Lot_No']); ?>"><?= $row['Uo2_Lot_No']; ?></a></td>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

On the above view each distinct value or linked. How can i implement this. By clicking the each distinct value link it should fetch all appropriate distinct value and other fields  from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear

Can't you run another query on this page ..

your page controller `/admin/consignment1/con_table/uo2_lot_no`

```
$uo2_lot_no = $this->uri->segment(4);

$data = $this->db->select('*')->from('consignment')
->where('uo2_lot_no', $uo2_lot_no)->get()->result_array();
```